# Displaying paperclip content_type errors in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, paperclip, simple-form

I'm having an issue where the validation errors on my model's attachment field are not showing up in the view when trying to upload an invalid file type. My model is setup as follows:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  styles: {medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>"}

validates_attachment :avatar, presence: true,
  content_type: { content_type: /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/ },
  size: { in: 0..10.megabytes }
```

If I inspect the error in my debugger, I see the following:

```
(rdb:1) p @applicant.errors.to_hash
{:avatar_content_type=>["is invalid"]}
```

I know the validation is working, so I suspect the issue is that the error is on the "avatar_content_type" field and not on the "avatar" field. I found a [similar issue on the simple_form discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/c9waJjCS_Uc) and one of the suggestions is to use the error helper:

```
<%= f.input :avatar %>
<%= f.error :avatar_content_type %>
```

This sort of works, but does not include the markup and classes that the normal errors include and is not styled properly. Is there an approach that I am overlooking that would work with twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Uber hack, place this in your view above the form:

```
<% @applicant.errors[:avatar] << "Invalid avatar upload format" if @applicant.errors[:avatar_content_type] %>
```

Edit: better answer:

Do the same in the controller

```
def update
  @applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
  if @applicant.update_attributes(params[:applicant])
    # ..
  else
    @applicant.errors[:avatar] << "Invalid avatar upload format" if @applicant.errors[:avatar_content_type]
    render :edit
  end
end
```